# Rails if statement in controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is using Bootstrap tabs.
Each tab shows a dataTable that's rendered from a partial.
The dataTables are using ajax code that's defined in the files:
workorders3_datatable.rb and workorders4_datatable.rb.

This is the index code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<%= render :partial => "workorders/index7", locals: {workorders: @workorders, tab: 2} %>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
<%= render :partial => "workorders/index8", locals: {workorders: @workorders, tab: 3} %>
```

This is the controller code that I'm trying to make work:

```
def index

@workorders = Workorder.all
@tab = :tab

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  if @tab == 2
    format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
  else
    format.json { render json: Workorders4Datatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

end

I'm sure the `if` statement is wrong.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE1

(This is kind of hard to explain)

But, I need the json to come from the file `Workorders3Datatable` for tab2 and `Workorders4Datatable` for tab3.

So, how can I write an `if` stmt to test for tab2 vs. tab3?

UPDATE2

I changed the view code to this - but, it still uses `Workorders4Datatable` for both tab views.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <%= render :partial => "workorders/index7", :locals => {:workorders => @workorders, :tab_id => 2} %>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
  <%= render :partial => "workorders/index8", :locals => {:workorders => @workorders, :tab_id => 3} %>
<div>
```

And the controller to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  puts "PUTS +++++++++++++ tab_id:" + params[:tab_id].to_s
  if params[:tab_id] == 2
    format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
  else
    format.json { render json: Workorders4Datatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

The `puts` statement shows tab_id to be nil
THE CONTROLLER ISN'T GETTING THE PARAM

UPDATE3

I'm trying something different - have separate actions in the controller

View code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <%= render :partial => "workorders/index7", :action => :index2 %>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
  <%= render :partial => "workorders/index8", :action => :index3 %>
</div>
```

Controller (I had to leave index or it wouldn't display)

```
  def index
  puts "PUTS +++++++++++ index"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
  end

end

  def index2
  puts "PUTS +++++++++++ index2"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
  end

end

  def index3
  puts "PUTS +++++++++++ index3"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: Workorders4Datatable.new(view_context) }
  end

end
```

It ends up using `index` all the time.

PS - also tried

```
<%= render :partial => "workorders/index7", :action => "index2" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but the `if` statement may be failing because `Workorder.all` will never return `nil`. If there aren't any workorders persisted in the DB it will just return `[]`. You should be doing

```
if @workorders3.present?
```

Comment: I cannot but agree, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Either `@workorders3` or `@workorders4` would return all the workorders.  I need an if stmt to know if the user clicked on tab2 or tab3.  I probably don't even need to have `@workorders3` and `@workorders4`.

Comment: I changed my question to get rid of `@workorders3` and `@workorders4`.

Comment: You will need to pass a parameter in the ajax call that tells you  wich tab originated it (/my_ajax_call/index?tab_id=2) and then in the controller check for the value of that parameter: `if params[:tab_id] == '2'`

Comment: Pablo - I really appreciate your help!  I'm not sure where to set the `tab_id=2`.  I tried `<%= render :partial => "workorders/index7?tab_id=2", locals: {:workorders => @workorders} %>`.  Should it be in the `locals`?

Answer (score 0):

An ActiveRecord query could not be `nil`, but it could be `empty?`